# What is the idiomatic approach to perform elementwise addition to an Array of Arrays in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have an `Array[Array[Float]]` for which it is guaranteed that all inner arrays are of the same length. I want to perform elementwise addition on all inner arrays.

Let me illustate this with a concrete example. Let's say my Array contains three Arrays consisting of seven Floats, with the following values:

```
Array[Array[Float]] = Array(
                          Array(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0), 
                          Array(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 
                          Array(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
                      )
```

Now I want to transform this into an Array of size 7, of which the n-th element is the sum of n-th elements in my input `Array`. For my example input the output would be:

```
Array[Float] = Array(1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0)
```

For performing this operation on two `Array[Float]`'s I know I can zip them and then add the elements with a map. I still struggle however to find a more generic solution that is able to sum any number of `Array[Float]`'s elementwise.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
scala> a.transpose.map(_.sum)
res1: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0)
```

Comment: transpose actually  copy the whole 2D array... isn't there a way without copy?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach,

```
(0 until a(0).size).map (i => a.map(_(i)).sum)
res: Vector(1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0)
```

And a version that relies on parallel collection `ParSeq`, which may prove more efficient for a (very) large number of input rows,

```
(0 until a(0).size).par.map (i => a.map(_(i)).sum)
res: ParVector(1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0)
```

Comment: `a.head.indices.map( i => ... )`

Answer (score 2):

You can also zip 2 arrays and combine with a reduce.

```
a.reduce {(x,y) => (x zip y).map{case (xi,yi) => xi + yi}}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Marth's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24907724/1206998) is best usually (more simple and readable). However if your input data is big, you might want to use a "lazy" version of `transpose`:

```
def transposeIterator[A](a: Seq[Seq[A]]): Iterator[Seq[A]] = {
  val iterators = a.map(_.iterator).view
  if(a.isEmpty) Seq[Seq[A]]().iterator
  else a.head.iterator.map( _ => iterators.map( _.next ) )
}
```

Example:

```
val test = (1 to 100).map( _ => (1 to 100000) )

test.transpose.map( _.sum )  // OutOfMem after a long time

transposeIterator(test).map( _.sum ).toVector // ~0.2 sec
```